# Iptables 'Accept' rule doesn't work

Tags: iptables

I setup a VPN server on my private VPS, the OS is CentOS 7.Now I want this VPN server can only be used to visit websites, so I'm going to use iptables to reject all output tcp ports except port 80 and 443 for the server.

1, I added a nonroot user 'ssuser'.

```
useradd ssuser
```

2, Run VPN server as this user.

3, Add iptables rules.

```
 iptables -t filter -m owner --uid-owner ssuser -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -t filter -m owner --uid-owner ssuser -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -t filter -m owner --uid-owner ssuser -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

4, iptables -L shows me this output:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    OUTPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1000 tcp dpt:80
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1000 tcp dpt:443
4    REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1000 reject-with tcp-reset
```

Unfortunately, the Accept rule doesn't work, all ports are blocked.My VPN server can't visit any website unless remove the 4th rule.

According to the order of the rules, should iptables accept the port 80, 443 first and then reject the rest of ports?

Can somebody tell me what I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you can show iptables filter you need use command "iptables -L -t filter". I recommend add -vvv "iptables -L -t filter -vvv". It command showy you more details.